# Long Click in document provider

Tags: android

I would like to know how to listen for long clicks inside DocumentsProvider of API 19+

currently It does normal click if i release on it or cancels if i release after swiping out of the item

this is the code i want to trigger

```
//finish document provider returning folder
```

which of these would i have to insert my code into or is it another one

```
public class LocalStorageProvider extends DocumentsProvider {

@Override
public Cursor queryRoots(final String[] projection) throws FileNotFoundException {}

@Override
public AssetFileDescriptor openDocumentThumbnail(final String documentId, 
final Point sizeHint,
        final CancellationSignal signal) throws FileNotFoundException {}

@Override
public Cursor queryChildDocuments(final String parentDocumentId, final String[] projection,
        final String sortOrder) throws FileNotFoundException {}

@Override
public Cursor queryDocument(final String documentId, final String[] projection)
        throws FileNotFoundException {}

private void includeFile(final MatrixCursor result, final File file)
        throws FileNotFoundException {}

@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openDocument(final String documentId, final String mode,
        final CancellationSignal signal) throws FileNotFoundException {}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {}
}
```

[image: how to set long click documents provider android]

Comment: which may be expanded to right click style menu if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a system-supplied UI. You have no means of changing its behavior. This includes having no means to decide to hook up a long-click listener and add a menu to it.

Comment: I thought I couldn't because I tried some things and none worked so anyway do you know of a way to get the folders path or should i implement a new activity for that purpose?

Comment: @Yeh: I do not understand the question. If you want the user to pick a folder, start an `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` activity.

Comment: That's what I meant by "implement a new activity" so there's no way of reusing the same document provider that i have already, and thanks for your quick response